# Can an inserted <script> tag be run multiple times without using eval in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser, eval

I have to use a plugin which bundles js files inside html files (gadgets). For one use case I need to drop and re-instantiate a gadget to run updated code.

So say I have `foo.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>...</body>
</html>
```

and `foo.js` which is the file being injected into my actual document's head:

```
alert("hello");
```

Problem is I can only cachebust the html file dynamically and declare my gadget as `foo.html?x=123`, but the JS file I'm after will still be `foo.js` so the browser will not re-run it.

**Question**:
Once a `<script>` tag is inserted into the document and run, is there any way to run it again without using a module-loader or eval?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your code in your `<script>` tags in a function then call your function. This will allow you to call your code to be called multiple times. Like this:

```
<script>
    function loaded(){
         // JavaScript here
    }
    loaded();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: hm. good point. I think I have to re-phrase my question... I need the script to be loaded again, because the user updated the code. You answer is correct, so I'm going with it. Thanks!